# Need to add and find element index value in arraylist in powershell?

Tags: powershell, powerpoint, powershell-remoting

add string element in arraylist and find it's index value?

```
[code...]
$eventList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$eventList.Add("Hello")
$eventList.Add("test")
$eventList.Add("hi")
```

Not working throwing error:-

```
Method invocation failed because [System.String[]] doesn't contain a method named 'Add'.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\qwedqwe.ps1:9 char:15
+ $eventList.Add <<<< ("Hello")
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Add:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Comment: This works just fine. Could you show the first seven lines of the script as well?

Comment: I am using these method also to find index value but not able to find it ...Could u please help me in it?                                                                  1. $index =$evenList.FindIndex({param($s) $s -match 'cv[u-z]'});
2.   (0..($eventList.Count-1)) | where {$eventList[$_] -eq 'hi'}
3 .  [array]::indexof($eventList,'hi')

Comment: `ArrayList` doesn't implement `FindIndex()` - sure it shouldn't be a `List[string]`? Again, please show us the entire context

Comment: Only this much content i m using before implementing in my main program since not able to fetch the index value i m not implementing in my main program

Comment: I'm asking because the error message says the exception is thrown at line 9, I'm wondering whether you are (strongly) casting `$eventList` to another type prior to the lines you've shown. Unless you can reproduce the condition with the lines you've posted, it's gonna be hard to help you - can you even do that yourself? Open a new `powershell.exe` session and paste only those four lines and tell me if you get the same error

Comment: #$a = Get-Content D:\Powercel\TimeStats\TimeStats_1slot\29_12_2015_07TimeStats1.txt
<#
$ParamsPathForData = ($dir + "\TimeStats\TimeStats_1slot\29_12_2015_07TimeStats1.txt")
$data = Get-Content $ParamsPathForData -Encoding Unicode
#>
#$eventList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string] 
$eventList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$eventList.Add("Hello")

$eventList.Add("hi")
$eventList.GetType().FullName
#$index =$evenList.FindIndex({param($s) $s -match 'cv[u-z]'});
# (0..($eventList.Count-1)) | where {$eventList[$_] -eq 'cc'}
[array]::indexof($eventList,'hi')

Comment: Please update your question instead, comments are not fit for code :)

Comment: Above code is i already commented so i hope it is not making any problem at all......

Comment: If you're executing this in PowerShell ISE and have already assigned `$eventList` previously it might have a type attribute bound to it. Again, open a new session (Ctrl + N) and let me know if you can reproduce the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, if you've developing this in ISE (or another IDE) and previously assigned `$eventList` with a type cast, like so:

```
[string[]]$eventList = @()
```

or similar, commenting out previous lines won't help you - the variable already exists and will have that type bound to it for the remainder of its lifetime.

You can remove any previous assignments with `Remove-Variable eventList`

---

Once you've got that sorted, we can move on to actually locating the index. If you're interested in the index of an exact match, use `IndexOf()`:

```
PS> $eventList.IndexOf('hi')
2
```

If that isn't flexible enough, use the [a generic `List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx), which implements `FindIndex()`.

`FindIndex()` takes a *predicate* - a function that returns `$true` or `$false` based on input (the items in the list):

```
$eventList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]
$eventList.Add("Hello")
$eventList.Add("test")
$eventList.Add("hi")
$predicate = {
  param([string]$s) 

  return $s -like 'h*'
}
```

And then call `FindIndex()` with the `$predicate` function as the only argument:

```
PS> $eventList.FindIndex($predicate)
0
```

(it matches `Hello` at index 0 because it starts with an `h`)

Comment: $eventList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$eventList.Add("Hello")
$eventList.Add("test")
$eventList.Add("hi")
$eventList.GetType().FullName

[array]::indexof($eventList,'hi')   Now i am using this code on fresh tab but still it shows  this error  Cannot find an overload for "IndexOf" and the argument count: "2".
At line:8 char:17
+ [array]::indexof <<<< ($a,'yellow')
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Comment: Or can u please give me the sample to find the location of element in an arraylist ???

Comment: @LovepreetSingh I've updated the answer, `ArrayList` and `List<T>` both implement `IndexOf()`, you don't need to call `[array]::IndexOf()`